# How to make WFS request using LeafletJS

Tags: leaflet, wfs

In the past I have used OL extensively in order to make WFS requests to Geoserver and add layer on a map.
Now I am trying to learn LeafletJS and I want to do something similar.
I have made a WMS request successfully but I can not find documentation of how to do WFS request.
This is the WMS request to geoserver:

```
var layer_name = L.tileLayer.wms("http://something:xxxx/geoserver/wms", {
        layers: 'workspace:geoserver_layer',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        version: '1.1.0',
    });
    layer_name.addTo(map);
```

Also, how do I solve the problem with the proxy. I remember in OL I used a cgi script.

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129965/how-to-add-geoserver-wfs-to-leaflet-js-application ?

Comment: I have made it partially work using this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187937/loading-geojson-layers-from-geoserver-to-leaflet-map-based-on-the-current-boundi

Comment: The problem is i get an error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access. When I click the link I see all the response as JSON.

Comment: Sounds like a [cross domain policy request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue. Basically, the page is hosted via one name-server (i.e. localhost, etc), and it is requesting assets from another name-server (i.e. something:xxxx, etc). Does that sound like your current setup? ...honestly I forget how to go about fixing that while testing on localhost. Check out [the advice in this blog post](http://williambert.online/2013/06/allow-cors-with-localhost-in-chrome/) ..does it help?

Comment: Nope. Not really. I was reading that if I use JSONP I can avoid the proxy solution. I will have to try to configure my geoserver installation to use JSONP and I will let you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, if you're getting the 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present' you have two options:

1. Enable [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/)
2. Enable [JSONP](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57494/geoserver-2-3-how-to-enable-jsonp).

Personally, I'd enable both.

JSONP can be enabled with an environment variable, by the way, which makes it nice and easy. On Linux you can do this:

```
export ENABLE_JSONP=true
```

And then start Tomcat.

For enabling CORS using Tomcat, I use this snippet:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

That goes in your web.xml file, which is located at $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml. Note that also in this file is a commented out section that can enable JSONP:

```
  <!--
  <context-param>
    <param-name>ENABLE_JSONP</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  -->
```

Uncomment that and you've got some JSONP format available as a WFS request.

If you have a reverse proxy, you can set up CORS there, just look at the docs.

FYI, the difference between JSON and JSONP is that JSONP is wrapped in a function, which for some reason is interpreted differently than regular JSON.

Here's an example loading a dataset into Leaflet using JSONP: https://github.com/alexgleith/maps-website/blob/master/glenorchy_mtbp.html

Comment: What's your environment? Are you running GeoServer in tomcat?

Comment: Yes. Tomcat6 on Ubuntu machine. But I have a rather old version of geoserver (2.5)

Comment: Well, if you can find the web.xml file and edit it, you'll be sorted! Let me know if I can help you out further.

Comment: Well I found the xml. What is interesting is that there is not an uncommented section of 'Enabling JSONP'. I am thinking if is not supported at all by Geoserver 2.5 or should I add it?

Comment: Try adding it. Then restart tomcat (should be 'sudo service tomcat6 restart') and see what happens! You can always undo your changes.